# Attribute always None

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, scraper

I've been trying to create a web scraper that collects the name, price and the district of an object on a website but cannot do anything with it because it raises an error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'.

What do I do? Help! Also how do I go to the second div? When I do `districtcontainers = souped.find_all("div",{"class":"announcement-block-link")` and then `districtcontainers[0].div.div`, it gives 0 output. How to solve that? Thank you very much for your attention and answers :).

```
import urllib.request as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


url = uReq.urlopen("https://www.bazaraki.com/real-estate/houses-and-villas-rent/larnaka-district-larnaca/")
html = url.read()
souped = soup(html,"html.parser")
containers = souped.find_all("div",{"class":"announcement-block-text-container"})
districtcontainers = souped.find_all("div",{"class":"announcement-block__location"})
for container in containers:
    for districtcontainer in districtcontainers:
        title = container.a
        price = container.p
        district = districtcontainer
        print("{}:\n Costs: \n District:{}".format(title.string.strip(),price.string.strip(),district.string.strip()))
```

Comment: Try `title.text` or `title.content`?

Comment: trying, it says EOF error yet

Comment: It works,but it returns every item like a hundred times

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Are you really using soup.find_all()? Instead you should be using soup.findAll()

Comment: It repeats the same thing a million times. e.g. Villa for rent is printed a hundred times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your last print statement has only two {} but you have three variables in the following format call, it's just a typo so it isn't the cause of the problem.

Second, it looks like one of your variables is getting assigned a value of None by your call to the souped object. Just check the page's coding to make sure the values you are looking for are found in the right position. BeautifulSoup will return None if you call for a section that isn't there instead of raising an error.

Since it looks like the exception is being raised while running the print call just check to make sure your three calls return values for your variable assignment.

As for getting to the second div in a page, you may want to check out the next_sibling method call.

Comment: Could you please help me with the .div.div thing? .next_sibling returns "\n". I can't parse any page because of this

Comment: You can use multiple next_sibling on a single instance so it may take multiple next_sibling to get to the actual text or the next instance of an HTML element.

I suggest next_sibling and possibly next_element because they assure that a value returned instead of creating another Nonetype error you're getting.